# Active Sessions Performance Counter for Web Server

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, performance-monitoring, session

I would like to monitor the number of active sessions for my ASP.Net 4.0.  It is hosted on IIS7 Windows 2008 Server.

When I looked at the Performance counter, I saw many instances.  How could I know which instance is the application instance I want to monitor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use appcmd.exe in System32\inetsrv.

`appcmd list apppool`, `appcmd list wp`, `appcmd list app`, etc., will help you match up app pools and worker processes.